# How does changing one of AES encryption stages affect its security?

Tags: aes

With regard to AES encryption on **blocks**, the next diagram showcase how does a **change** in one cell in the block (every cell is a byte) creates a change in encryption for ALL cells:
[image]

Now I have the next question, from a network security course:
Say we change the "Mix Columns" stage to be "Rotate Clockwise", that works as follows:
[image]

**Is the new AES now more vulnerable to chosen-plaintext attacks?**
So far, I've noticed that a change in one cell leads to a change in encryption for only one cell, but not neceserally to same cell. So a change in cell 1,1 can change the encryption of cell 3,3.
And this is where I got stuck. It seems that the answer is to save the mappings of all different cells, but how can I do that, when a change in one cell alters the encryption of a different cell?

Comment: So, after one round, the value of cell 3,3 is a function of the keys and which input cells (and specifically, which input cells is it **not** a function of).  Does this same behavior continue throughout the modified AES cipher?  How does this behavior permit various attacks (they stated chosen-plaintexts; I would include known plaintext and ciphertext only in the list, although those attacks are slightly less straight-forward)

Comment: @poncho I'm sorry, I don't think I understand. The value of encryption of cell 3,3 might be dependent on any other cell in the block. I already knows the answer is aiming for a table attack, but I'm not sure what mappings I should save.

Comment: Are you wondering what happens when the MixColumns permutation stage is _completely replaced_ with a bytewise transposition instead?

Comment: @forest Yes, or more importantly, what attack can be done on the modified AES

Comment: Let's try a simpler cipher: suppose we have a block cipher with a 16 bit block size; we consider the input as two cells of a byte each - the cipher swaps the cells, and then sends each cell through an unknown sbox.  How would you attack this cipher?

Comment: @poncho I could, in addition to the mappings of each cell that I meantioned in OP, save a function that gets a cell number, and returns the number of the cell that would be affected by a change in the given cell. In this instance, cell 1 maps to 2 and cell 2 maps to 1. Now I can attack with chosen plaintext. I understand that I can do the same thing here, but here - there's a lot of cells that can alter the encryption of a single cell. It's not a one on one map.

Comment: :It's not a one on one map." - it isn't???

Comment: @poncho In regard to the function I've defined? yes, there are multiple cells that, if you change their message, the change in encryption will appear in the same cell.

Comment: At what step does that happen?  In the new step (rotate clockwise)?  Or, in one of the other three steps (addroundkey, subbytes, shiftrows)?